# Optimal Neural Network Structure for 'Crystal Rush': Single vs. Modular Networks?

Tags: neural-networks, training

[image]

#### Problem

I'm attempting to design a neural network for the bot programming game [Crystal Rush](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/crystal-rush). Given the game's complexity, I anticipate needing a vast neural network to manage bot movements, resource requests, and world perception. By large, I mean an input and output list smaller than the length of 50.

I have already created a simple neural network for a codingame puzzle called Code vs. Zombies with five sensors on the front and three in the back, with four output neurons to control movement. A replay of my neural net is [here](https://www.codingame.com/replay/734017598).

#### Game Rules (Brief Overview)

- Bots start on the board's left edge and can move towards cells to collect ore.
- Bots collect minerals and return them to the headquarters (left side) for points. They deposit their haul in the leftmost collum of the board.
- Initially, bots can't see the board. They can deploy radars to unveil sections. Radars are placed by mining specific grid cells.
- Bots can set mines by mining a cell. If another bot mines this cell, it explodes, destroying that bot. Mines are invisible to radars.
- A bot can only hold one ore. After mining an ore, it has to go back to the base to deposit it.
- For detailed rules, visit [here](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/crystal-rush).

#### Potential Approaches:

- **Decompose the Problem:**
  Should I break down the problem such that each neural network only commands a single bot, replicating this for all bots on the board?
- **Further Decomposition:**
  Should I segment the tasks for each bot across multiple neural networks (modular neural networks)? This could allow each network to specialize in a specific task, potentially speeding up training.

#### Question

Given the above, what's the best approach to designing a neural network for this game? How do I structure the neural network for optimal performance in this game? A structure that would give enough data to the NN for it to make good enough decisions without making the weight and biases list grow too large to get meaningful training in a manageable time frame